# Can you help me understand this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a snippet of code from this "simple client management system" I've found and i'm trying to understand. (link to source code: https://www.sourcecodester.com/php/15027/simple-client-management-system-php-source-code.html).

There are two tables `invoice_list2` and `client_list` but I sincerely do not understand the `i` and `c` meaning in the query.

Please tell me if you need more information, thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
  i.*,
  c.fullname  
from 
  `invoice_list2` i 
    inner join client_list c 
      on i.client_id = c.id 
order by 
  unix_timestamp(i.date_created) desc
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `js`, `html`, `php` and `database`? That's a "how does SQL work" question...

Comment: @Andreas agreed, I cleaned it up :-)

Comment: These characters are **aliases**. Now you know the terminology, you can easily get more info: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+alias. They're just a shorthand way of referring to the tables, largely to make the query a bit more readable.

Comment: Notice how the i and the c are present after the table name. That is where they are defined as aliases.

Comment: sorry man i'm new here and i thougth more tags the faster the answer.

Comment: Not if the tags don't actually have anything to do with the question / problem! That just gets your question put in front of people for whom it has no relevance and therefore unsurprisingly get grumpy about clicking on something that was nothing to do with their area of interest/expertise.

Comment: that's why title exists;

Comment: It's mentioned in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): _"All questions are tagged **with their subject areas**."_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you everybody for the answers, really appreaciate also you modified the question.

Comment: i also thought that if someone knows php could respond, sorry Andreas, i'll be better

Comment: _"that's why title exists;"_ - Then what topic is your title about? "Query" is as specific as "car" -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: i understand, sorry good boy

Comment: You can't assume someone who knows PHP will understand anything about SQL. And even if they do, you also can't assume that they're interested in answering SQL questions right now, if they came to the question via the [list of PHP questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

Comment: go capido porcodeundio, it means i've understood and the next time i'll be better in italian dialet

Answer (score 3):

The `i` and `c` are aliases for the tables `invoice_list2 (i)` and `client_list (c)`.

So the `SELECT i.*, c.fullname` means "get every column from the table `invoice_list2` and the column `fullname` from the table `client_list`".

**Edit due to comment question:**

The alias is specified directly after the table is mentioned e.g.

`from invoice_list2 i` <--

`inner join client_list c` <--

Both time at the end the alias is set. You could also write `from invoice_list2 as i` and `inner join client_list as c`. The `as` is optional and you can decide yourself if you want to use it or not.

Comment: thanks, where it is specified that "i" means invoice_list2 and "c" means client_list?